# i want to select all record from table with group by count is greater than 5

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get all record from a table where agent_no = 70 and group by home_number,agent_no Having count(*) >1

```
SELECT 
*
FROM user_data
WHERE agent_no = 70
GROUP BY
  home_number,
  agent_no
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT 
*,
COUNT(*) AS count
FROM voters_data
WHERE booth_no = 70
GROUP BY
  hno,
  booth_no
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(*) AS count FROM voters_data WHERE booth_no = 70 GROUP BY   hno,   bo' at line 4

Comment: The queries don't match the error message...

Comment: You're missing a comma. Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after the booth_no

```
....
booth_no
COUNT(*) AS count
....
```

should be

```
....
booth_no,
COUNT(*) AS count
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the fields.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), home_number, agent_no FROM user_data 
WHERE agent_no = 70 GROUP BY home_number, agent_no HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: i want to get all record like select * from user_data and then group by home_number and agent_no